# React Native how to clip the camera image for QR scanning

Tags: react-native, qr-code, clip

This is my first time using react native and I'm trying to create a QR code scanner. I notice that as I increase the camera size on screen, it is harder for me to get the exact scanning region of the camera. Therefore, may I know if there is any method that works like clip-path in react native so that I can clip off the corner of the image?

Or if there's a way to draw a box near the scanning region?
Something like this:
https://lh4.ggpht.com/4cA87gd0VFuGXLbl76fR27gEwimDRtTR_HzT59pKN5YVbnTvmr6rnbnOa6amDGqD9hs=h900